# copy paste text in label in QTableWidget cell PyQt5

Tags: python, pyqt5, copy, qtablewidget

I have multiple QTableWidget in my application:

[image: My Application window]

I want to be able to copy the text stored in a cell when selected either by pressing ctrl+c or by right-clicking on it and clicking on a 'copy' menu.

The tables I am using are costumized, and this is the code that implements em:

```
class AlphaPiQTableWidget(QTableWidget):
    def __init__(self, attr_dict):
        super(AlphaPiQTableWidget, self).__init__()
        values = list(attr_dict.values())
        attributes = list(attr_dict.keys())

        # Tabella che mostra i valori del competitor
        self.setRowCount(len(attributes))
        self.setColumnCount(2)
        self.setCellWidget(0,0, QLabel(attributes[0]))
        self.setCellWidget(1,0, QLabel(attributes[1]))
        self.setCellWidget(2,0, QLabel(attributes[2]))
        self.setCellWidget(3,0, QLabel(attributes[3]))
        self.setCellWidget(0,1, QLabel(str(values[0])))
        self.setCellWidget(1,1, QLabel(str(values[1])))
        self.setCellWidget(2,1, QLabel(str(values[2])))
        self.setCellWidget(3,1, QLabel(str(values[3])))

        self.setContextMenuPolicy(QtCore.Qt.CustomContextMenu)
        self.customContextMenuRequested.connect(self.showTableMenu)

        # Fai occupare tutto lo spazio libero nel layout alla tabella
        h_header = self.horizontalHeader()       
        h_header.setSectionResizeMode(QtWidgets.QHeaderView.Stretch)
        h_header.setVisible(False)
        
        v_header = self.verticalHeader()       
        v_header.setSectionResizeMode(QtWidgets.QHeaderView.Stretch)
        v_header.setVisible(False)

        # Fai in modo che la tabella sia sempre visualizzata per intero
        self.setVerticalScrollBarPolicy(Qt.ScrollBarAlwaysOff)
        self.setHorizontalScrollBarPolicy(Qt.ScrollBarAlwaysOff)

    def showTableMenu(self, pos):
        # get the text of the index at the mouse cursor (if any)
        text = self.indexAt(pos).data()
        menu = QtWidgets.QMenu()
        copyAction = menu.addAction('Copy')
        if not text:
            copyAction.setEnabled(False)
        # show the menu
        res = menu.exec_(QtGui.QCursor.pos())
        if res == copyAction:
            # if the menu has been triggered by the action, copy to the clipboard
            QtWidgets.QApplication.clipboard().setText(text)
```

The issue is that when I copy the text by right-clicking on a cell and pressing on 'copy' `self.indexAt(pos).data()` always returns `None`. Why is that?

P.S. all the `AlphaPiQTableWidget` are stored on a QHBoxLayout along with other widgets (such as labes and buttons as you can see.

Comment: Why are you using labels?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That there are cells does not imply that there are items, in your case you have placed widgets on top of the cells, so in reality you want to get the text of those QLabels.

The first thing is to obtain the QLabel using the cellWidget method, but for this it is necessary to obtain the row and column of the pressed cell, in which case the indexAt() method must be used:

```
def showTableMenu(self, pos):
    index = self.indexAt(pos)
    label = self.cellWidget(index.row(), index.column())
    text = label.text()
    # ...
```

Another solution is not to use QLabels but rather QTableWidgetItem:

```
self.setItem(0,0, QTableWidgetItem(attributes[0]))
# ...
```

Comment: Thank you so much!!! THat solved the problem. I am quite a noobie with PyQt and I oculdn't figure out what was wrong.

Comment: @giuliodizio also, have a look at [how to paste and copy out multiple cells values in qt table widget](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62997198/2001654) for a basic example of copy&paste using context menu.